# New Thread inside a Thread in WinRT

Tags: c#, multithreading, async-await, c#-5.0, winrt-async

I am performing certain functionality in a ThreadPool. Inside this thread, linq query will be executed. This takes more time because, in that query selects a collection of my class also has a bool property that checked for another two collection.

```
collection.Select(item => new MyElement { IsActive = this.CheckIsActive(collection1, collection2, item), Value = item, Name = item != null ? item.ToString() : "Empty" }).ToList<MyElement>();
```

CheckIsActive Method----

```
private bool CheckIsActive(List<object> collection1, List<object> collection2, object item){
 if (collection1.Contains(item) && !collection2.Contains(item))
     return false;
 return true;}
```

can this optimized? Any Idea?

can use a new thread for the above execution in a new thread?

can use Thread or await for a return type method?

Comment: When posting code to Stack Overflow (and in general!), please consider breaking it into multiple lines rather than having one very long line that everyone has to scroll. Additionally, your question is pretty unclear at the moment. I'm not at all sure whether you're trying to ask a question about LINQ or trying to ask a question about asynchrony. We don't even know whether this is a "local" LINQ query or not. (One thing I *can* tell you though: if you could change `collection1` and `collection2` to be HashSets, that may well speed things up a lot, if they're big.)

Comment: @JonSkeet: please explain about Hashset comapision..

Comment: @Sankarann: Well checking for containment in a HashSet is O(1), whereas checking for containment in a List is O(N). It doesn't matter for small collections, but if your collections aren't small, it could radically reduce the operation time. But you haven't given nearly enough information for us to really say whether that will help you or not.

Comment: sure, am little bit confused what should i use to optimize time. That's what i was asked about both.